# Переключение CSS классов в Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap

Как можно в Bootstrap сделать так, чтобы при определенной ширине экрана элемент использовал правила одного из своих классов, а при другой - из другого?

В Bootstrap например, есть классы ширины колонок - `col-xs`, `col-md`, и т.д., при изменении размера экрана элементы используют класс с префиксом, соответствующим размеру - `xs` для телефонов, `sm` для планшетов и т.д.

Comment: Добавьте JavaScript. При изменении размера окна, меняйте все классы элементов с `sm` на `xs`, `md` на `sm` и так далее.

Comment: @VisioN, "При изменении размера окна, меняйте все классы элементов с sm на xs, md на sm и так далее." - Дак это и так автоматически работает в Bootstrap

Comment: Простите, *что именно* Bootstrap меняет автоматически? Классы всех элементов переписывает? Вы должны явно указывать разные классы для разной ширины сетки, т.е. `col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-7`.

Comment: @VisioN, Я указываю с sm на xs, md на sm и так далее. Мне вот именно нужно добавлять свои отступы для каждого экрана, потому что, если писать col-xs-1 - двигает на слишком большой отступ для меня, а мне нужно меньше. В Bootstrap плохо что нельзя писать так: col-xs-0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `@media` запросы. Например, есть класс `.test`, Который мы хотим видеть только на телефоне. Тогда необходимо написать такие стили:

```
.test {
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .test {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну и как вы хотите изменять классы элементов с помощью `@media` запросов? Ваш совет совершенно не подходит к данной ситуации.

Comment: @Rolandius Спасибо, хороший способ. Но есть ли другие варианты в Bootstrap? Что-то находил про less.

Comment: @VisioN, так как `Bootstrap` делает для большинства своих классов это автоматически, я понял этот вопрос так, как будто он относится к собственным классам.

Comment: @Дмитрий, `Bootstrap` предполагает, что вы можете изменить переменные в их `less` коде для изменения количества колонок, точек входа медиа запросов, размера шрифтов и т.д. Но для добавления новых "фич", Вам придется дописывать то, что я и описал в ответе все равно.

Comment: @Rolandius, А можно в Bootstrap делать отступ например на пол колонки только? - col-lg-0.5

Comment: @Дмитрий, можно изменить общее количество колонок `@grid-columns`. Если написать, что их будет не `12`, а `24`, вы добьетесь того, чего хотите. Надо не забыть потом скомпилировать стили.

Answer (score 1):

использование разных классов, в зависимости от ширины экрана, можно организовать с помощью классов (уж простите за тавтологию) hidden-* и visible-* где * может быть xs,sm,md и т.д. Назначение этих класов скрывать либо показывать элементы к которым они применены.

с помощью этих классов можно для каждой ширины сделать свой вариант разметки.
вот пример который виден только на малых экранах, соответственно вы можете подкинуть к этому объекту например класс customClassSM

```
<div class="customClassSM hidden-xs visible-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
...
</div>
```

вот вариант который виден уже на средних экранах и к нему можно применить класс customClassMD соответственно

```
<div class="customClassMD hidden-xs hidden-sm visible-md hidden-lg">
...
</div>
```

скомбинировав таким образом вашу разметку можно достичь нужного результата. Вот пример для всех разрешений

```
<div class="customClassXS visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
применяется класс customClassXS</div>
<div class="customClassSM hidden-xs visible-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
применяется класс customClassSM</div>
<div class="customClassMD hidden-xs hidden-sm visible-md hidden-lg">
применяется класс customClassMD</div>
<div class="customClassLG hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md visible-lg">
применяется класс customClassLG</div>
```

В итоге у Вас одновременно только один элемент будет с классом visible-* и соответственно его customClass* и будет применен

Comment: Да спасибо. Идея тоже не плохая, думал уже так делать. Но это удобно только для небольшого изменения, но когда мне нужно менять отступы во всей шапке сайта при различных экранах, это придется дублировать постоянно... слишком получится объемно.

Comment: А можно в Bootstrap делать отступ например на пол колонки только? - col-lg-0.5

Comment: @Дмитрий честно говоря, когда я с такой задачей сталкивался то для себя ее так и не решил.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам необходимо делать свои отступы или ширину и прочие вещи, тогда вам для нужного разрешения экрана придется отказаться от классов бутстрапа, это как вариант, и написать свои, при этом указать в css @media запрос для нужной ширины и уже там задавать отступы. Так же можно отслеживать js изменение размеров экрана и добавлять / удалять заранее прописанные классы css без всяких @media. И еще вариант писать свои миксины в less / sass, там есть наследование и можно создать свои классы с нужными вам параметрами.